# Como atribuir matriz de caracteres em uma estrutura?

Tags: c, array, struct

O programa faz a leitura de 10 filmes, cada filme tem nome  gênero, e classificação etária, depois os lista;

Não estou conseguindo atribuir matriz de `string` (creio que só seja esse erro)

```
   #include <stdlib.h>
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <strings.h>

   #define quantidade_filmes 10
   #define tamanho_filme 30

typedef struct
{
char nome_filme[quantidade_filmes][tamanho_filme];
char genero_filme[quantidade_filmes][tamanho_filme];
int classificacao[quantidade_filmes];
/*0- menor que 18 anos
1-maior que 18 anos*/
} Dados;

 int main()
{
Dados dados[quantidade_filmes][tamanho_filme];
int i;

for(i=0; i<tamanho_filme; i++)
{
    system("CLS");
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("Cadastrando filme de numero %i \n",i+1);
    printf("Digite o nome do filme:\n");
    scanf("%[^\n]",&dados[i].nome_filme);
    printf("Qual o genero do %s ? \n",dados.nome);
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%[^\n]",&dados[i].genero_filme);
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("O filme e para maiores de 18 anos? 0-nao 1-sim \n");
    scanf("%d",&dados[i].classificacao);
    fflush(stdin);
}

for(i=0;i<quantidade_filmes;i++){
printf("NOME: %s\n",dados[i].nome_filme);
printf("GENERO: %s\n",dados[i].genero_filme);
if(dados[i].classificacao==0){
    printf("FILME DESTINADO AO PUBLICO MAIOR DE 18 ANOS\n");
    }        else{
        printf("FILME LIVRE PARA TODOS OS PUBLICOS\n");
  }
               printf("\n");
  }

  }
```

Comment: Explique melhor sua dificuldade.

Comment: O compilador acusa erro na hora de leitura dos dados.(o primeiro for inteiro)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O código tem uma quantidade enorme de erros, não é só o que está descrito. Nem sei se vou falar de todos.

Está misturando conceitos. Ou cria um vetor de filmes dentro da estrutura ou fora, nos dois não faz sentido. Na verdade dentro também não faz neste caso, então deixe só fora.

Já que há uma macro com a definição do tamanho da *string* de nomes, vamos dar um nome melhor para ela e colocar um caractere a mais para o terminador.

Resolvi da forma adequada a leitura do *buffer*, o que tinha usado não funciona em todas situações.

Como os dados que são `string` já são ponteiros não precisa passar por referência.

Note que simplifiquei e organizei o código também.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#define quantidade_filmes 2
#define tamanho_nome 31

typedef struct {
    char nome_filme[tamanho_nome];
    char genero_filme[tamanho_nome];
    int classificacao;
} Dados;

int main() {
    Dados dados[quantidade_filmes];
    for (int i = 0; i < quantidade_filmes; i++) {
        printf("Cadastrando filme de numero %i \n", i + 1);
        printf("Digite o nome do filme:\n");
        scanf("%[^\n]\n", dados[i].nome_filme);
        printf("Qual o genero do %s ?\n", dados[i].nome_filme);
        scanf("%[^\n]\n", dados[i].genero_filme);
        printf("O filme e para maiores de 18 anos? 0-nao 1-sim\n");
        scanf("%d\n", &dados[i].classificacao);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < quantidade_filmes; i++) {
        printf("NOME: %s\n", dados[i].nome_filme);
        printf("GENERO: %s\n", dados[i].genero_filme);
        if (dados[i].classificacao == 0) printf("FILME DESTINADO AO PUBLICO MAIOR DE 18 ANOS\n\n");
        else printf("FILME LIVRE PARA TODOS OS PUBLICOS\n\n");
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/CTWubh). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/nbkpzmel-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Struct/Array.c).

Comment: Agora eu entendi , muito obrigado.